# Detecting Walls in Multidimensional Arrays C++ Issues

Tags: c++, arrays

> I need some help figuring this out. For some reason, when I move along
>   my array say for example "e" for east, I have made a detect wall
>   collision so the player can't go any further. However, when I try to
>   go "w" for west (back) it goes back 2 instead of 1. Any ideas on how
>   to fix this?

For now, use the e button to go right and west button to go left. I've used a multidimensional array and a switch to detect what room you're in, also providing player coordinates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int playerX = 0; // x
int playerY = 0; // y

int nextX; // pY
int nextY; // pX

bool win = false;

string move;

char dungeon[11][11] = {

{ 's','c','c','c','r','w','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 'w','w','w','c','w','r','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',},
{ 's','c','c','r','r','c','c','c','c','r','r',}

};

void movePlayer();
void location(int X, int Y);

int main()
{
    do {

        movePlayer();
        location(playerX, playerY);

    } while (win == false);

}

void movePlayer() {

    string move;
    cin >> move;

    // reference Grid-Cave-Mk1 Author: Heather Southall Date: 2017

    if (move == "n") {
        nextY = playerY - 1;
        if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 11)) {
            playerY = nextY;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Can't move there" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "e") {
        nextX = playerX + 1;
        if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 11)) {
            playerX = nextX;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Can't move there" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "w") {
        nextX = playerX - 1;
        if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 11)) {
            playerX = nextX;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Can't move there" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "s") {
        nextY = playerY + 1;
        if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 11)) {
            playerY = nextY;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Can't move there" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void location(int X, int Y) {

    cout << "X: " << X << endl;
    cout << "Y: " << Y << endl;

    char local = dungeon[Y][X];

    switch (local) {
    case 's':
        cout << "Starter Room" << endl;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cout << "Corridor" << endl;
        break;
    case 'r':
        cout << "Room" << endl;
        break;
    case 'w':
        nextX = playerX - 1;
        if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 11)) {
            playerX = nextX; playerY = nextY;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that happens EVERY time you enter 'w', and not only when you move onto a 'w'  location ?   It wouldn't be a bad idea to have a `cout << "Western Room" << endl;` in the `location` method to highlight when that's the case.

Comment: There's also the fact that nextX and nextY aren't initialized, but are used in the 'w' case of location().  Let's hope they were used before that happened.

Comment: It's only when it reaches the 'w' in the array. When I try to go back from this, it goes back two spaces instead of one (e.g. 5 to 3).

Comment: You should print out the actual room (before both functions) instead of the room tested by `location(x, y)`.
You're at [4, 0]. You move towards the wall (e). It prints [5, 0], but it moves you back to the room at [4, 0]. If you move west, you'll be at [3, 0]. Hence you get logs [5, 0] -> [3, 0].

Comment: Unrelated: If you put the position of the player it in a `struct position_t { int x, y; ... }` and add member functions like `position_t& operator+=(const position_t&)` you can isolate and fix problems with less effort than you need right now. It also helps when presenting problems for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an issue with misleading logs - you don't print the current position, but the one which "type" is being checked. So you can get to logs [5, 0] and [3, 0] when:

- You move east from the [4, 0] room. You check what's at [5, 0] (**first print**). You hit a wall, so the current position is moved back to [4, 0].
- Discouraged, you move west. You check what's at [3, 0] (**second print**).

You should change the printed message, so that the user is notified about both the current position, and the tested one.

---

ps. hitting a wall should move you to the previous location instead of translating the position by [-1, 0].

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought by doing nextX = playerX - 1;, I was moving back a space. Would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: It's moving you back, but only if you're coming from the west side.
If you'd move the player in `location()`, and use `move()` only for setting `nextX` and `nextY`, then you'd have both the current location and new location available in `location()`. It would kindof change the functions to `checkNext()` and `movePlayer()`.
But if you don't want to reorganize atm, you can just store a `prevX` and `prevY` at the beginning of `move()`.